# Нормально ли использовать условия во втором аргументе useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, hook

Так правильно?

```
data && data.id
Если нет, то почему?

const { data } = props;

useEffect(() => {

}, [data && data.id]);
```

Тут нету повторяющихся перерендеров, всё работает шикарно, но почему-то мне сказали, что так делать не нужно.
Кто-нибудь может объяснить мне почему?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
  if (data && data.id) {}
}, [data]);

Comment: data - объект - ссылка на объект не меняется, не подходит.  RavenTheX